# SQL INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have the below query:-

```
CREATE TABLE #FCO3
(TYPE_CODE varchar (100),
 SKU varchar (100),
 QtyOnHand int);

INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005060','1);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005066','8);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005067','1);
```

It is throwing out an error of:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 109
>   Incorrect syntax near 'FC03'.

Can anyone help on what is causing this as I must be missing something obvious

Thanks.

Comment: remove the quote before the 1, 8 and 1

Comment: Your syntax highlighting here is already letting you know ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have unmatched quotes around the quantity

try:

```
CREATE TABLE #FCO3
(TYPE_CODE varchar (100),
 SKU varchar (100),
 QtyOnHand int);

INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005060',1);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005066',8);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005067',1);
```

Comment: great thanks.  I've been staring at this so long I couldn't see the obvious!

Comment: happens to us all sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:-

```
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005060',1);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005066',8);
INSERT INTO #FCO3 (TYPE_CODE, SKU, FREQUENCY) VALUES ('FC03','1005067',1)
```